How to disable Google Lens in search when using Google Chrome?
Google Chrome enabled Google Lens with August 2024 update.
How to disable Google Lens lens when searching using Google Chrome?

Before the update:


Go to chrome://flags/ in your Google Chrome and search for Lens overlay (or go to chrome://flags/#enable-lens-overlay).
Change it to Disabled and relaunch Google Chrome.

Let's hope they don't remove this flag in the future...
